# Populating ListView from webservice pagination

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I have a database and a table data. The table havs thousands of records. My requirement is to display 1000 records on a ListView

For that I have a WebService. When I invoke the WebService URL in Android, it returns 10 records (each time I invoke the WebService which returns 10 records max)

I'm able to display the 10 records on my ListView for the first invocation of the WebService.

But my requirement is to display the records in pagination format or LoadMore button?

Could any one tell me the process of loading those 1000 records on my ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you need is here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

As your question is too vague, it's nearly impossible to answer everything here, I hope the link and the library will help